# change price based on qty in grouped woocommerce products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

My need is to display gross weight and net weight of the products and change the gross weight and net-weight based on the quantity. While change the qty the net weight and gross-weight also should change. It was working fine in single product page while coming to the grouped products unable to achieve this.

Here is my single product working fine: https://hamarafresh.com/product/salmon/

Here is my grouped products not working: https://hamarafresh.com/product/lady-fish/

I am getting gross weight and net weight from custom field.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_quantity_input_field', 'woocommerce_total_product_price', 31 );
    function woocommerce_total_product_price() {
        
         if ( is_product() ) {
             
        global $woocommerce, $product;
        
        $gross_weight = get_post_custom_values($key = 'gross_weight');
           $net_weight = get_post_custom_values($key = 'net_weight');
        get_post_meta( $post_id, $key, $single );
        // let's setup our divs
      ?>
    <?php $netweight5= esc_html( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'net_weight', true ) ); ?>
                
    <?php $grossweight5= esc_html( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'gross_weight', true ) ); ?>
    
                <?php
          echo sprintf('<div id="net_weight_disp" style="margin-bottom:10px; margin-top:7px;">%s %s</div>',__('Net Weight:'),'<span class="price">'.$netweight5.'</span>');
        
        echo sprintf('<div id="gross_weight_disp" style="margin-bottom:10px; margin-top:7px;">%s %s</div>',__('Gross Weight:'),'<span class="price">'.$grossweight5.'</span>');
        
          echo sprintf('<div id="product_total_price" style="margin-bottom:20px; text-align: center;">%s %s</div>',__('Product Total:','woocommerce'),'<span class="price">'.$product->get_price().'</span>');
         
        
        ?>
            <script>
                jQuery(function($){
                    
                    var price = <?php echo $product->get_price(); ?>,
          
                        currency = '<?php echo get_woocommerce_currency_symbol(); ?>';
                    
    <?php   $net_weight = get_post_custom_values($key = 'net_weight'); ?>;
                    
                    <?php $netweight5= esc_html( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'net_weight', true ) );   ?>;
                    
                     var net_weightt = <?php echo $netweight5; ?>;  
                     
                     
                     <?php   $gross_weight = get_post_custom_values($key = 'gross_weight'); ?>;
                        <?php $grossweight5= esc_html( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'gross_weight', true ) );   ?>;
                     var gross_weightt = <?php echo $grossweight5 ?>;   
    
                     
                     
                     
                    $('[name=quantity]').change(function(){
                        if (!(this.value < 0.5)) {
                            
                            var net_weighttt = (net_weightt* this.value);
                            var gross_weighttt = (gross_weightt* this.value);
                            var product_total = parseFloat(price * this.value);
    
                            $('#product_total_price .price').html( currency + product_total.toFixed(2));
                            
                         $('#net_weight_disp .price').html( currency + net_weighttt.toFixed(2));
                            
                             $('#gross_weight_disp .price').html( currency + gross_weighttt.toFixed(2));
    
                        }
                    });
                });
            </script>
        <?php
    }
    
    }
```

[image: custom field]
[image: Grouped product page]
[image: Single Product page]

Comment: name quantity in single product is fine but in grouped is not. So define which qty field you click to update :)

Answer (score 0):

Change this line `$('[name=quantity]').change(function(){`

like below

```
`$("input[name^='quantity']").change(function(){`
```

**Updated Answer**

```
 $("input[name^='quantity']").change(function() {
    if (!(this.value < 0.5)) {
        if ($(".woocommerce-grouped-product-list-item").length > 0) {
            var nw = $(this).closest("tr").find(".net_weight_disp").data("netweight");
            var cw = $(this).closest("tr").find(".gross_weight_disp").data("grossweight");
            var pdt = $(this).closest("tr").find(".product_total_price").data("price");
            var net_weighttt = (nw * this.value);

            var gross_weighttt = (cw * this.value);
            var product_total = parseFloat(pdt * this.value);

            $(this).closest("tr").find('#product_total_price  .price').html(currency + product_total.toFixed(2));
            $(this).closest("tr").find('#net_weight_disp .price').html(net_weighttt.toFixed(2));
            $(this).closest("tr").find('#gross_weight_disp .price').html(gross_weighttt.toFixed(2));

        } else {
            var nw = $(this).closest(".right_summary_content").find(".net_weight_disp").data("netweight");
            var cw = $(this).closest(".right_summary_content").find(".gross_weight_disp").data("grossweight");
            var pdt = $(this).closest(".right_summary_content").find(".product_total_price").data("price");
            var net_weighttt = (nw * this.value);

            var gross_weighttt = (cw * this.value);
            var product_total = parseFloat(pdt * this.value);

            $(this).closest(".right_summary_content").find('#product_total_price  .price').html(currency + product_total.toFixed(2));
            $(this).closest(".right_summary_content").find('#net_weight_disp .price').html(net_weighttt.toFixed(2));
            $(this).closest(".right_summary_content").find('#gross_weight_disp .price').html(gross_weighttt.toFixed(2));
        }
    }
});
```

Because grouped products name attribute will be array.

Comment: hi sir, it is changing the value but it changed all the product values instead of single product value....can you help me regarding this

Comment: Need to use '$(this)'

Comment: @M.Lak, My answer updated. It is not tested.

Comment: Also you getting only one value for `net_weightt` in grouped products. you need to change this as dynamic. not static variable values.

Comment: hi sir i tried your answer it is taking only the last value of the product: http://hamarafresh.com/product/seer-fish/  here is the example.

Comment: it only taking last array value to all products.

Comment: Yes. Also you getting only one value for net_weightt in grouped products. you need to change this as dynamic. not static variable values.

Comment: You are using only one value `var net_weightt`

Comment: hi can you guide me how make this as a dynamic variable?

Comment: `var net_weightt` should be an array. Need your code to check. So I can guide you. Or you should use ajax when you click on increment button. In ajax function you can calculate the net weight.

Comment: full code is in my question only bro

Comment: @M.Lak, I want to setup woocommerce like your product page. Also want to setup custom fields also. It may take time.

Comment: can i share my login info. sir can i get your email ?

Comment: i sent mail sir can you pls check